# WebSphere Portal 7: use rss/atom feed as a content provider for portlets. Is it possible?

Tags: rss, websphere-portal, atom-feed

Is there any way to use atom feed as a content provider in WebSphere Portal 7?

Let's say I have 2 portlets on a page which are representing main part and footer. I have one atom feed with 2 entries. I need to show the first entry as html in the main part and the second entry as html in the footer.
Please, advise any solutions based on your experience or confirm that it is only possible to do by writing your own custom portlet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand the requirement for the feed to display the first link in one portlet and the next link in a different portlet, but you could try using the Syndicated Feed Portlet. Here is an explanation: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/catalog/doc/1wp1001p3/index.html
Here is the download from Lotus Greenhouse: https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=AAC7B8951F4C69CA8525771C004993D7
This allows you to integrate a feed with minimal portlet customization.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this portlet. It acts as a Google Reader actually. Also it allows you to change templates for representing feeds. I am currently using it. But it looks a little bit heavy so I am searching for something lightweight.

Comment: Let me know what you find, I'd love to take a look at it.

Comment: It's not a "Portal" solution, but the Google Feed API is all done in front-end Javascript: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/

Comment: What I've done in order to implement what I wanted:
1. in META-INF/services folder of Syndicated Feed portlet I changed com.prudential.feed.PortletChannelAgentFactoryImpl file. I put my own implementation of com.ibm.wps.portlets.feedspace.ext.PortletChannelAgentFactory
2. As I said I had implemented PortletChannelAgentFactory. You need to implement createPortletChannelAgent method which will return your version of com.ibm.wps.portlets.feedspace.ext.PortletChannelAgent
3. Your implementation of PortletChannelAgent should implement fetchFeed where I processed feed in a way I needed it.

Comment: 4. And the last thing in portlet.xml I changed 2 preferences:
channel.template and headlines.template to link to my implemenetation of these jsp pages.
5. Then I repackaged this portlet and deployed it.